# share env variable beween turborepo monorepo project

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, monorepo, turborepo

I ve setup a basic turborepo project and I want to share `.env` variables across the all the apps and some of packages. If I set one `.env` file in the root of project and how can all apps and packages access them. Or for my requirement do I need to set multiple `.env` files in all apps and packages?

Answer (score 10):

As of December'22, the recommended way of doing this as per the official [`turbo` docs](https://turbo.build/repo/docs/handbook/dev#tutorial) is as follows:

1. `cd root-directory-of-your-project`.
2. `npm add -D dotenv-cli` (or with `pnpm`: `pnpm add -D dotenv-cli -w`).
3. Create a `.env` file in the root directory of your project.

   - Add your `.env` to your project's root `.gitignore`.
4. Add your variables to the newly created `.env` file.

   - If you are using `nextjs` remember to prefix your public variables with `NEXT_PUBLIC_*` (example: `NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TOKEN=1234`).
5. On your `turbo.json` file, add the variables on which each `pipeline` job depends.

   - Example:

   ```
   {
     "$schema": "https://turborepo.org/schema.json",
     "pipeline": {
       "dev:frontend": {
         "outputs": ["dist/**", ".next/**"],
         "env": ["NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TOKEN"]
       },
       "dev:backend": {
         "outputs": ["dist/**", ".next/**"],
         "env": ["DATABASE_URL"]
       }
     }
   }
   ```
6. Restart your local development server. Try logging `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TOKEN`.

Once finished, the structure of the project should look similar to the following:

```
apps
    backend     <<< Your backend code. You don't need to keep any .env file here.
    frontend    <<< Your frontend code. You don't need to keep any .env file here.
package.json    <<< Where you should install dotenv-cli as a dev dependency.
turbo.json      <<< Where pipeline jobs and their dependencies on environment variables are specified.
.env            <<< Where all your environment variables will be stored.
```

Answer (score 3):

Following [turbo docs](https://turbo.build/repo/docs/handbook/dev#using-environment-variables) - Using environment variables

Steps:

1. Add [dotenv-cli](https://github.com/entropitor/dotenv-cli#readme) to the project root.

```
# Installs dotenv-cli in the root workspace
yarn add dotenv-cli --ignore-workspace-root-check
```

2. Update the root script (what runs your project with turbo), in my case "dev"

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "dotenv -- turbo run dev",
    ...
}
```

you may leave the turbo default globalDependencies setup in *turbo.json*

```
"globalDependencies": ["**/.env.*local"]
```

Optional:

3. If you have a CRA, create a .env.local in the CRA app root and expand the variable

in workspace root .env:

```
VARIABLE=value
```

in CRA root .env.local:

```
REACT_APP_VARIABLE=${VARIABLE}
```

Restart server.

Answer (score 2):

To load the env variables from .env into the process env you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv.

Then to share the env variables in your monorepo :

In each workspace/app add `require('dotenv').config({path: /custom/path/to/.env})` (assuming common js module resolution here) as early as possible as per docs (meaning e.g. for a next js app in next.config.js), where `/custom/path/to/.env` would be the relative path to your root .env (e.g. two folders up:`../../.env`)

Comment: This won't work for shared workspace libraries though... as the relative path will be changed compared to the library files.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the `globalDependencies` option in your turbo config or use the `--global-deps` CLI flag.

```
{ 
   // ... rest of the turbo config
   globalDependencies: ['.env']
}
```

or

```
turbo run build --global-deps=".env.*"
```

References from docs:

https://turborepo.org/docs/reference/configuration#globaldependencies
https://turborepo.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#--global-deps

Comment: but it's not loading any env variables...

Answer (score 1):

The `globalDependencies` mentioned on the other answers is like the docs says:

> A list of file globs for implicit global hash dependencies. The contents of these files will be included in the global hashing algorithm and affect the hashes of all tasks. This is useful for busting the cache based on .env files (not in Git) or any root level file that impacts workspace tasks

So, it's needed to cache that specific task, build etc... on turbo caching but not to load it on the application.

To load env variables from a centralized `.env` file into multiple processes, you may use my new package https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-mono, which was designed specifically for this purpose.

1. Install dotenv-mono (`yarn add dotenv-mono` or `npm install dotenv-mono --save`)
2. Place your `.env` file in the root of your project
3. Then load it as follows on your packages/applications init file (`index.{js,ts}`, `next.config.js`, etc...):

   ```js
   require("dotenv-mono").load();
   ```

Check out the github page for more documentation https://github.com/marcocesarato/dotenv-mono

Answer (score 1):

This package [@dotenv-run/cli](https://github.com/chihab/dotenv-run) might help.

`.env.* files` can be defined in the root workspace and overriden by each application

```bash
/workspace
 apps
    frontend1
       .env.local # API_USERS=http://localhost:3001/users
       src/
.env.dev # API_BASE=https://dotenv-run.dev
.env.prod # API_BASE=https://dotenv-run.app
.env # API_USERS=$API_BASE/api/v1/users API_AUTH=https://$API_BASE/auth
package.json
turbo.json
```

```bash
$> cd /workspace/apps/frontend1
$> NODE_ENV=dev dotenv-run -- bash -c 'printf "✨API_USERS $API_USERS\n✨ API_AUTH $API_AUTH"'
✔ /workspace/apps/frontend1/.env.local
✔ /workspace/.env.dev
✔ /workspace/.env
✨ API_USERS http://localhost:3001/users
✨ API_AUTH https://dotenv-run.dev/api/v1/auth
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Add dotenv-cli, in your project root

```
npm add -D dotenv-cli
```

2. update script

```json
"dev": "dotenv -- turbo run dev",
```

3. Add .env file to the project root

From [Docs](https://turbo.build/repo/docs/handbook/environment-variables#loading-your-own-variables)

Answer (score 0):

I've found this approach to work.

1. Install `env-cmd` (`yarn install env-cmd`)
2. Make a shell script called `turbo-run.sh` that does the following:

```bash
# remember to use direct paths to files because yarn has a habit
# of stripping out `--` flags (which are used in turborepo to pass
# in extra args to turbo commands)
./node_modules/.bin/env-cmd \
  --file $ENV_FILE \
    ./node_modules/.bin/turbo run \
      $@
```

(also `chmod +x` it so that you can execute it)

3. Then setup your package.json scripts to have a `turbo-run` command that calls `./turbo-run.sh`
4. Now you can do `yarn turbo-run foo` and ensure that it always calls `env-cmd` with the appropriate ENV_FILE file.